# ¿Cómo actualizar automáticamente la versión de mi proyecto en NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

Tengo la duda de cómo podría hacer para actualizar la versión de mi proyecto automáticamente.

Usaría un postbuild con una flag, ¿o habría una manera más eficiente y fácil de hacerlo? porque yo supongo que cuando yo tengo ya una versión estable que funcione de mi proyecto y que es diferente de la anterior en ese momento debería actualizar la versión de mi proyecto.

Estuve buscando en algunas páginas y no encontré una respuesta clara, y también busqué en youtube y nada.

No sé si es que hay algo que no entiendo.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones, en stack overflow es mal vista por la comunidad este tipo de preguntas, por lo que probablemente termine cerrada, y si alguien sabe la respuesta es posible(puede que no) que te deje un comentario con un consejo.

Comment: No se nada de tu codigo o nodejs,react. Pero normalmente siempre recomiendan que uses la version mas actualizada(estable) de lo que uses en el servidor(para evitar hackeo por vulnerabilidades recientemente parchada. Pero no se, no programo en estos lenguaje

Answer (score 1):

Con npm puedes hacer [`npm version [ patch | minor | major ]`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-version)

Esto provocara un cambio de versión y creará una nueva etiqueta en tu repositorio de git.

Tambien puedes utilizar algo más automatico como [standard-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-version).

La forma habitual de usar esta librería es crear un script `release: standard-version` dentro de tu `package.json`. La funcíon básica te permite recopilar los datos de los commits que no han sido versionados, generar o agregar los datos a un fichero `CHANGELOG.md` y crear una nueva etiqueta en tu repositorio.

Si estas publicando librerias puedes usar algo más pro como [np](https://www.npmjs.com/package/np) que te permitirá correr tests, ejecutar código personalizado, publicar directamente en npm, agregar tags, entre otras cosas.

Comment: Entiendo que con npm puedo cambiar la version, pero como haria para no tener que color por ejemplo npm version patch, cada vez que quiera compilar mi proyecto, yo habia pensado algo asi como un prebuild que tenga npm run patch, pero tendria que hacer eso para minor y major tambien entonces no me parece el mejor camino a seguir

Comment: Busca la documentacion de `standard-version` y lee sobre el versionado semantico 2.0. Hace exactamente lo que pides solo con un comando. Los commit deberían de llevar esta estructura: `fix: este es un parche`, `feat: Este es un cambio menor` y `feat: breakingchange - Este es un cambio mayor`. El cambio de versión lo hace de manera automática mientras respetes el [versionado semantico](https://semver.org/lang/es/)

Comment: ya entendí lo que quisiste decir, disculpa, gracias, busque la documentación y pude entender lo demás,